# Do all voices deserve rests, or can I tactically omit rests?

Tags: piano, notation, engraving, rests

The voice 3 (magenta) plays for just two semiquavers at the end of the bar:

[image: measure without voice-specific rests]

should I add a series of rests for that voice?

[image: measure with complete rests for each voice (in color)]

it's hard to understand which rests belong to which voice when rendered in black-and-white:

[image: measure with complete rests for each voice (in black and white)]

we could merge the voices (hard to see that only the E is tied):

[image: measure with separate voices written as single voice]

---

Well, probably the pragmatic answer is to just relax the interpretation (this is a piano arrange of a multi-instrument song) and say that the notes don't overlap:

[image: measure with voices merged and overlapping notes removed]

but nevertheless: if we *were* to try and notate the semiquavers + minim scenario: are all of the aforementioned representations legal? which would be preferred?

Comment: Related: [Unplayed 2nd voice in notation - spaces or rests?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/56445/unplayed-2nd-voice-in-notation-spaces-or-rests), [In keyboard style harmony should there be a rest for each voice?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/122328/in-keyboard-style-harmony-should-there-be-a-rest-for-each-voice)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elaine Gould, in her standard reference to music notation, *Behind Bars*, indicates that "Parts on one stave share a rest where possible" (p. 312) Thus, the initial half rest should be shared between the magenta and green voices.

In the second half of the measure, there should be a quarter rest and an eighth rest in the magenta voice so that it's clear the green voice is separate. (Again according to Gould, a dotted quarter rest is not permitted. "The longest permitted dotted rest is one value smaller than the beat. In crotchet [X/4] metres, the longest dotted rest is a dotted quaver [eighth note]" [p. 162].)

[image: Example of rest distribution]

It also would clean things up to move the "repeated A" voice to the upper staff. If desired, ["handedness brackets"](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103442/70803) can indicate which As to play with which hand. (In MuseScore, these are found on the Master Palette in the Symbols list under Keyboard techniques.)

[image: Example with voices redistributed]

Comment: "permissible" under what authority?  (Furthermore, every authority I'm aware of forbids dotted rests except to represent integral beats in compound meter, so it's more than preferable to use two rests; it's required.)

Comment: @phoog Elaine Gould's authority.

Comment: Thanks.  It might be interesting to see what other standard references have to say on the matter (I have the sense that older works would have separate rests, but I don't know when the preference changed).  But I don't have any at hand.

Comment: It's worth noting that Gould (on p. 313) also notes that:  
"_In strict contrapuntal writing, each part takes separate stems and rests throughout._"